# Can I develop a multiplateform mobile application for my ASP.net web application using phonegap or cordova?

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, mobile, hybrid-mobile-app, multi-device-hybrid-apps

I developed a web application using ASP.net and Angularjs, CSS and html for front end, I want to create a cross-platform mobile application so is it possible to use cordova or phonegap to do it?

Answer (score 0):

If as I think you're using WebAPi in your ASP.NET app and no mvc controller because your angularJS app is the entire Front end, you just have to drop your angular app in a cordova/phonegap project ( with maybe some little fixs ) and enjoy

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. But after a little research, I discover that Cordova does not perform well, so I think to move to develop a cross-platform mobile application. Actually, I'm searching to choose the best across-platform.I will be thankful for your suggestion if you have any idea about it.

Comment: If you want to keep an Javascript environment , "React Navite" is maybe a good solution ( and you drop AngularJS for ReactJs ). If not you can see Xamarin, views are in natives languages  ( per platform ) and code is in C#, nice performance btw.

There are others technologies, good luck to find what you are looking for.